# something about the result of Date(long date )

Tags: java, date

The JDK1.8 API saies the result of the Date(long date) is based on the time January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT, but when I test it by set the date=0, I find the result is not the  Thu Jan 01 08:00:00 CST 1970, it's not the 00:00:00,but the 08:00:00,why?[the result about the Date(long date)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTTAj.png)

Comment: CST is 6 hours from GMT, not 8, so this is still a bit odd  Set your timezone to GMT and try again.

Comment: @Tibrogargan (US) 'Central' ST is 6 hours _behind_ GMT (hence 18:00 the previous day), but China ST is 8 hours ahead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.EPOCH.toString()
```

> 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z

```
Instant.EPOCH.atZone( ZoneId.of( "America/Chicago" ) ).toString()  // Use proper time zone names (continent/region). Avoid pseudo-zones such as `CST`, which could be Central Standard Time in US or China Standard Time.
```

> 1969-12-31T18:00-06:00[America/Chicago]

```
Instant.EPOCH.atZone( ZoneId.of( "Asia/Hong_Kong" ) ).toString()
```

> 1970-01-01T08:00+08:00[Asia/Hong_Kong]

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

You are using you using old date-time classes, now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

Among its many problems, the `toString` method of `java.util.Date` implicitly applies the JVM’s current default time zone while generating a string. Avoid this class.

## java.time

Instead use `Instant`. Represents a moment on the timeline in UTC with a resolution of nanoseconds.

```
Instant.ofEpochSecond( 0 ).toString()
```

> 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z

Or use the constant for that value, [`Instant.EPOCH`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#EPOCH).

For current moment in UTC, call `now`.

```
Instant.now()
```

To adjust into a specific time zone, search Stack Overflow for `ZonedDateTime` and `ZoneId`.

Adjust into another time zone. Same moment, same simultaneous point on the time line, but different wall-clock time.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Hong_Kong" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

With a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) complying with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later, you may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. No need for strings or java.sql.* classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

It's because of your timezone.
If you change the time zone to GMT it will show `00:00:00`

```
Date date = new Date(0L);
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
System.out.println(date);
```

Output : `Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT 1970`

Comment: got it ,i didn't notice the difference between "GMT" and "CST"

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

**It is because of the `TimeZone` set, by default by the JVM when & where you run the program**, look at the below statement from the Java doc.

> Typically, you get a TimeZone using getDefault which creates a
>   TimeZone based on the time zone where the program is running. For
>   example, for a program running in Japan, getDefault creates a TimeZone
>   object based on Japanese Standard Time.

You can look at [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html)

Comment: it is bacause of the TimeZone , the default of mine is "CST", not the "GMT"